# pod で上手く辞書機能が使えません

Tags: python

botを作る以下のコードで「こんにちは」以外認識されず、また上手く返答されません。
入力文字はutf8で、pythonはバージョン3.6を使用しております。

```
bot_dict = {
    'こんにちは': 'コンニチハ',
    'ありがとう': 'ドウイタシマシテ',
    'さようなら': 'サヨウナラ',
    }

while True:
    command = input('pybot> ')
    response = ''
    for key in bot_dict:
        if key in command:
            response = bot_dict[key]
            break

        if not response:
            response = '何ヲ言ッテイルカ、ワカラナイ'
        print(response)

        if 'さようなら' in command:
            break
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

インデントのせいで、返答を表示する

```
if not response:
    response = '何ヲ言ッテルカ、ワカラナイ'
print(response)

if 'さようなら' in command:
    break
```

の部分まで、`for`ループの中に入っているのが原因です。

少しコードを追ってみると、'こんにちは'を入力したとき

```
for key in bot_dict:
    if key in command:
        response = bot_dict[key]
    　　break
```

の`if`文の条件にマッチしますが、`break`でループを抜けるので返答部分をスキップしてしまい、`response`が表示されません。

また、'ありがとう'を入力すると、最初に'こんにちは'と比較してループを抜けないため、返答部分を実行しています。